# Using patterns to match all but main domain and www in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a setup where I allow users to choose a subdomain or to add their own custom domain names. The problem is that some of my routes "clash". One of those being the `/` route.

First, I added a domain group around all *base routes* that filtered out only my domain name. Here is that version:

```
// Base routes
Route::domain(config('app.domain')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController')->name('home');
});

// Profile routes
Route::domain('{profileUrl}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@show')->name('users.show');
});
```

But then the *base routes* doesn't match `www.domain.com`. Which made me think that I should somehow use regex to exclude the domain + `www` from the *profile routes*. Meaning, the *base routes* would act as a fallback. So I changed my routes to this:

```
// Profile routes
Route::domain('{profileUrl}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@show')->name('users.show');
});

// Base routes
Route::get('/', 'HomeController')->name('home');
```

And tried excluding routes by registering a pattern like this:

```
\Route::pattern('profileUrl', '^(?!(domain\.com|www\.domain\.com)$).*');
```

But since the Laravel router uses `Str::is()` to match patterns, the regex doesn't work.

I am aware of that I could solve this using nginx, but that would require configuring all prod + staging + dev servers even more. I rather have that in my codebase.

How do I match all requests but main domain and www subdomain in a Laravel router group?